# I am getting a parse error code in PHP when the semi-colon is not needed

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error

I've been doing research on this error and still can't come about on how to fix this. I am also intrigued and curious on how I would prevent this issue from coming about again. I am using the Cloud 9 IDE. I am using an initialization file and will be sanitizing the files. It is stating that there need to be a semi colon after my `'host' => '127.0.0.1',`

I have also tried a PHP validator / Lint. Still is buggy and giving me the error.

The error I have gotten from my IDE is:

> Syntax error, unexpected ';' expecting ')'

As you can see I don't have a semi colon.

init.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $GLOBALS['config'] = array(
        'mysql' => array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ; 
            'username' => 'porixify',
            'password' => '',
            'db' => 'vomica'
        ),

        'remember' => array(
            'cookie_name' => 'hash',
            'cookie_expiry' => 604800
        ),

        'session' => array(
            'session_name' => 'user'
        )
    );

   spl_autoload_register(function($class)
    {

        require_once 'Classes/' . $class . '.php';

    });

   require_once 'Functions/santize.php';

?>
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Please post the actual error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ;
```

There *is* a semicolon.... very far along the line, column ~500.

Delete it, remove the whitespace, voilà:

```
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
```

Comment: No worries, @Porixify. If it worked, please mark it as the answer! :)

Comment: I will don't worry! I'm waiting for the four minutes to be up! :P

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, right, there is semicolon at line 7 (after `'host' => '127.0.0.1',`) column 496. Just turn on wrapping in your editor/ide and you will see.